# Intertwining map in Schur's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am learning Schur's Lemma from page 4 [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2010spring/projects/roy-representation-theory-ups-434-2010.pdf&ei=ogtZU-HNGcPnsATa1ILoBQ&usg=AFQjCNHDNTN_310iTrIJ2EwIvE5qO1dCwQ&bvm=bv.65397613,d.cWc&cad=rja). It says

**Schur's Lemma 1.** If $(\rho_1, V_1)$ and $(\rho_2, V_2)$ are irreducible representations of a group $G$, then
any nonzero homomorphism $\phi : V_1 \mapsto V_2$ is an isomorphism.

***Proof***. Assuming  $\phi$ is nonzero, we can write $v_2 = \phi(v_1) \in V_2$ for some $v_1 \in V_1$. We can
then say that $\rho_2(g)(v_2) = \rho_2(g)(\phi(v_1))$, which by the intertwining property of maps between
representations, gives that 
$\rho_2(g)(v_2) = \phi( \rho_1 (g)(v_1)) \in \phi(V_1)$ ...

Why the $\phi$ can commute with $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ in the expression above?

Comment: That's the definition of a homomorphism being applied to $\phi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A homomorphism between representations $(V_{1}, \rho_{1}), (V_{2}, \rho_{2})$ is exactly a linear map $\phi : V_{1} \rightarrow V_{2}$ such that for all $g \in G$,

$$\phi(\rho_{1}(g)(v_{1})) = \rho_{2}(g) \phi(v_{1}).$$

This is exactly what is going on in the proof above. $\phi$ is assumed to be a homomorphism and hence the action of $g$ commutes with the application of $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. It seems there are multiple usage of homomorphism, I am confused on what are definitions and what are derived properties.

Comment: You're welcome. That's not uncommon the first time you read some topic. Just go back to the definitions when you get stuck and try to parse through what the proof said.